# How to save picture viewed in iOS Safari to Files (iCloud)

Tags: iphone, ios, icloud, safari

Open safari, browse to a page with images, press and hold on the image, select "Share..."

There does not appear to be a way to 'share' the image to the Files app.
Yet there is an option for "save to dropbox".

How can I easily achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

If you open the image in its own tab (e.g. [open the direct image URL](http://www.kidssearch.com/picsearch/images/duck-pic-1024x768-bd7cff7.png))
you can tap the Safari share button to save the image to files.

When the share sheet opens it will give you options on what you want to share (see white arrow).

[image: Screenshot shows Save to Files on Safari Share Sheet]
*Enregistrer dans Fichiers = Save to Files*

Not showing Save to Files when holding the image is probably a bug. You should report this bug to Apple.

In the meantime, you can also create a Siri Shortcut that saves the input to the Files app, so you can save anything to Files even if it doesn't originally show on the share sheet. Your shortcut will always appear on the share sheet as an additional option, you don't need to ask Siri.

Answer (score -1):

There are two ways to do this.

1. `Save` the image to your photos, then open the photos app and view the image. Tap the `share` button and select `save to files`.
2. `Copy` the image, open the files app and `paste` it (long press) into the selected folder.

Comment: Whoever downvoted, this *used to be* the correct/only way of doing this, however, it is obviously not the case anymore. Not sure when exactly this changed though.

Answer (score -1):

You save it in Photos then go to Share in the lower left corner and then to File

Comment: Why take the detour via Photos?